# php file is returned as code without executing in wamp server

Tags: php, html, localhost, wampserver, wamp64

I want to access HTML  data in the PHP file to add two numbers. Below is the HTML code to take user input-

addnumber.html

```html
  <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form action="add.php" method="POST"> 
     <input type="number" name="fno"/>
     <input type="number" name="sno"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Below id the add.php file code

```
<?php 
 $a = $POST['fno'];
  $b = $POST['sno'];
  $ans = $a+$b;
  echo $ans;
?>
```

But after clicking the submit button in the chrome PHP code is shown instead of the result of two number addition.

Is the file code not running because I need to use localhost:8080 instead of localhost. Please help if possible.

Note: I can run PHP using http://localhost:8080/programs/add.php line.

Comment: have you tried using the whole url in the `action` attribute? like `action="http://localhost:8080/programs/add.php"`

Comment: It is showing  Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\programs\add.php on line 2 but I am not using xmpp, I am using wamp

Comment: Do I need to uninstall XMPP?

Comment: Check if all services in wamp are running. just put your cursor on top of WAMP icon, it will tell you like 3/3 running.

Comment: you have a typo. It should be `$_POST` not `$POST`

Comment: It is showing 1 of 3. What to do now

Comment: Vote to close this as a typo

Comment: How do you access the page "addnumber.html"? Is it's URL http://localhost:8080/programs/addnumber.html ?

Comment: I access the addnumber.html by opening it in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the port from 80 to 8080 for Apache and it works.